# Canvas behaves oddly at different sizes

Tags: javascript, canvas

Been playing around with canvas lately, but it behaves oddly at different sizes.

Here's my code:

HTML: `<canvas></canvas>`

CSS: `canvas { width:300px; height:50px; }`

JS:

```
var c = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillRect(10,10,50,50); // fill a 50x50 square at pos (10,10)
```

At canvas size 300x50, the following is drawn:

[image: canvas size 300x50]

At canvas size 100x200, the following is drawn:

[image: canvas size 100x200]

It's clear that one pixel does not actually mean one pixel - am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use CSS to change the size of the canvas.  Instead change the size of the element:

```
c.width=300;
c.height=50;
```

That's because when you resize with CSS you're "stretching" the pixels.  When you change the size of the element itself, you are actually adding/subtracting pixels.